# Php soap problem

Tags: php, soap

simple soap program in php where i can send user name and password to soap server and it return Boolean value

Comment: Could give us more informations about your problem ? And, maybe, ask a question ? That would help us help you ;-)

Answer (score 1):

Well, I'm guessing you need to read about PHP/Soap, so go ahead and check [PHP's Soapclient class](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.soapclient.php) and [apple's soap php tutorial](http://developer.apple.com/internet/webservices/soapphp.html).

I *highly* recommend reading this [FAQ](http://catb.org/~esr/faqs/smart-questions.html)